# Normal families of uniform covers

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

I am taking an undergraduate course in topology and am stuck with trying to prove the following Theorem from Willard:

36.11 Theorem. Every normal family of covers of X is a subbase for some uniformity on X; the converse fails

A normal family of uniform covers is defined as a family of covers in which each each cover in the family has a star refinement that is also in the family.

Thank you in advance for your time!!

Comment: I suppose it is... that or the fact that given a uniformity you won´t necessarily be able to find a subbase that is a normal family of covers (unless that is the same as what you´re saying, I am quite new to this field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\nu$ be a normal family of covers of $X$; define $\mu$ by the set of all covers $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ such that there are finitely many covers $\mathcal{V}_1, \mathcal{V}_2,\ldots,\mathcal{V}_n \in \nu$ such that $$\bigwedge_{i=1}^n \mathcal{V}_i \prec \mathcal{U}$$

Claim: this defines a uniformity $\mu$ and $\nu$ is clearly a subbase for it 
by definition.

Checking the axioms for a covering uniformity is straightforward: Let $\mathcal{U}_1,\mathcal{U}_2 \in \mu$, let $\mathcal{V}_1,\ldots, \mathcal{V}_n$ be the witnessing covers from $\nu$ for $\mathcal{U}_1$ and $\mathcal{V}_{n+1},\ldots, \mathcal{V}_{n+m}$ those for $\mathcal{U}_2$. 
For each $\mathcal{V}_i$ we can find a $\mathcal{W}_i \in \nu$ such that $\mathcal{W}_i \prec^\ast \mathcal{V}_i$ as $\nu$ is a normal family.
Then $\nu \ni \bigwedge_{i=1}^{n+m} \mathcal{W}_i \prec^\ast \mathcal{U}_j$ for $j=1,2$ so $\mathcal{U}_1$ and $\mathcal{U}_2$ have a common star-refinement in $\mu$. The enlargement axiom (b) is trivially fulfilled.

For the converse, which I interpret as "every subbase for a uniformity is a normal family", this is indeed false:

Let $X$ be any uniformisable space which is not paracompact in its induced topology (like $\omega_1$ in the order topology), and give it its fine uniformity $\mu$.

By Willard 36.16 the set $\nu$ of all open covers of $X$ is a base (so certainly a subbase too) of $\mu$.

But $\nu$ is **not** a normal family: as $X$ is not paracompact, by 20.15 it has an open cover without an open star-refinement.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer has made me realize my understanding of star refinements wasn´t 100% correct, which was what was creating difficulties. Thanks again!!

Comment: @ASB what were you missing about star-refinements?

Comment: I find them hard to understand and not a very intuitive concept in general! In particular, I was confusing certain concepts of them with ones from barycentric refinements

Comment: @ASB A barycentric refinement is like refining a cover of $B(x,r)$ by $B(x,\frac{r}{2})$, a star refinement is more like refining it with $B(x,\frac{r}{3})$; you take more "room to spare". A barycentric refinement of a barycentric refinement is a star refinement.

Comment: @ASB you could define a normal family also as one that every cover in it has a barycentric refinement in it. (instead of a star refinement). Those amount to the same thing in essence. But the definition of uniform stucture is in terms of star refinements of covers, not barycentric ones.

Comment: The analogy with the balls makes it much easier to grasp, thank you! It'll definitely help to not get lost in all the notation :)

Comment: You assume $X$ is not paracompact space, then you apply 36.16 which has paracompactness in its assumptions. Should be:Let $X$ uniformizable and not-paracompact in its induced topology, $μ$ its fine uniformity. By 36.15 $μ$ is generated by the collection $ν$ of all normal open covers, so if $\cal{U}\in$ $μ$ there is $\cal{V}\in$ $ν$, $\cal{V}\subset \cal{U}$ which has a star-refinement $\cal{W}$. $\cal{W}$ is then a star-refinement of  $\cal{U}$ too. Since the uniformity is fine, it follows any open cover of $X$ will have an open star refinement. So, $X$ is paracompact by 20.15. This is absurd.